# Polymorphism - Inheritance: Different Types of Constructors and Static - Dynamic Types of Objects

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism

```
class Top {
    float f = 1.0f;
    public void m1(Top a, short i){
        System.out.println("m1 (Top, short) in class Top");
    }
    public void m1(Top a, int i){
        System.out.println("m1 (Top, int) in class Top");
    }
    public void m1(Medium a, short i){
        System.out.println("m1 (Medium, short) in class Top");
    }
}
```

```
class Medium extends Top {
    float f = 2.0f;
    public void m1(Medium a, int i){
        System.out.println("m1 (Medium, int) in class Medium");
    }
    public void m1(Medium a, short i){
        System.out.println("m1 (Medium, short) in class Medium");
    }
}
```

```
class Bottom extends Medium {
    float f = 3.0f;
    public void m1(Bottom a, int i){
        System.out.println("m1 (Bottom, int) in class Bottom");
    }
}
```

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] b) {
        int i = 0;
        short s = 1;
        Top c1 = new Top();
        c1.m1(c1, i);
        c1.m1(new Bottom(),s);

        Medium c2 = new Medium();
        c2.m1(new Medium(), s);
        c2.m1(c1, s);

        c1 = c2;
        c1.m1(new Medium(), s);
        c1.m1(c1, s);

        Top c3 = new Bottom();
        c3.m1(c3, i);
        System.out.println(c2.f + "; " + c1.f + "; " + c3.f + "; " + (new Bottom()).f);
    }
}
```

What I don't understand in this code is, what happens when I just use "new Bottom()" as parameter? In which class should it be? And what happens when I equalize c1 and c2 (c1 = c2), Does c1 object change its class to Medium?

I researched a little bit and found something about "static type" and "dynamic type" but I still don't understand how this actually works?

It is obvious when I create a constructor like Top c1 = new Top(); but what is Top c3 = new Bottom(); or just new Bottom();

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you say Top c3 = new Bottom(); you're referring to Polymorphism. Polymorphism can be defined as an object pretending to be something else, usually a class it inherits or an interface it implements. Here, the object "b" is trying to pretend to be a Top, but in fact it's an instance of the Bottom class.

If you tried to execute c3.m1(.., ...), then the method inside the Bottom class is going to be executed if it's overriden.

We always start from bottom to top in the hierarchy. We first check if the method m1() exists in the Bottom class. If so, it's going to be executed. And since the Bottom class has the Medium class as its direct superclass, then the method m1 is going to be executed if it was overriden by the Medium class. If not, the method of the main base class (Top) will be executed. That's how method execution basically works when talking about Polymorphism.

When you make c1 = c2, then c1 would point to the same reference that c2 is referring to. So, in short, you would achieve polymorphism by doing so.